# Segmentation Fault in Hashtable

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50

I was trying to implement a hash table that stores the word of English language. So to be in brief, I used an array of linked list ( **Chaining** ) , I haven't made the entire program but just implemented so that It takes a single word input and searches it through the hash table but it starts giving me Segmentation fault. Please help me on this one....
Thank you in advance !

```
strcpy(new->s,val);
```

This is the line where I got stuck with the Segmentation Fault.

My entire code :

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node
{
string s;
struct node *next;
}node;

node* create(char*);

unsigned long sdbm(unsigned char*);

bool search(string s,node *first)
{
node *ptr=first;
bool found=false;

while(ptr->next!=NULL)
{
    if(strcmp(ptr->s,s)==0)
    {
        found=true;
        break;
    }

}

if(found==true)
return true;
else
return false;
}



int main(void)
{
node a[26];
printf("Enter the string\n");
string s=get_string();
unsigned long hashcode = sdbm((unsigned char*)s);
printf("The hashcode is %lu\n", hashcode);

a[hashcode].next=create(s);

printf("Enter the string to be searched among the ones you recently typed 
in\n");
string t=get_string();

if(search(t,&a[sdbm((unsigned char*)t)]) == true)
printf("found\n");
else
printf("not found\n");

}


node* create(string val)
{
node* new = malloc(sizeof(node));
if(new!=NULL)
{
    new->s="";

    strcpy(new->s,val);   // this is the part ehere I get Segmentation Fault
    new->next=NULL;
}

return new;

}

unsigned long
sdbm(unsigned char *str)
{
    unsigned long hash = 0;
    int c;

    while ((c = *str++)!=0)
        hash = c + (hash << 6) + (hash << 16) - hash;

    return hash%26;
}
```

Comment: `new` is not a good choice of a variable name. It will lead to confusion as it is a keyword in many languages

Comment: terrible mix of C and C++, many bad things occur

Comment: @Ed Heal Thanks  I will surely get to that ! Please tell me about the segmentation fault

Comment: Have you used a debugger to walk through the code

Comment: 1. You use ancient compiler. 2. cannot strcpy to C++ string. 3 I guess You have MANY warnings

Comment: @Ed Heal I've used a debugger but wasn't able to determine the error.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using a header file `cs50.h` which is not a standard c header file.You might know that in that header file there is a line `#define unsigned char* string` i.e here `string` is not `c++ string` it means `char*`.so whenever you uses `string` it will be interpreted as `char*`. In your code in `create` function there is an error

```
 node* create(string val)
 {
   node* new = malloc(sizeof(node));
   if(new!=NULL)
   {
      new->s="";   //ERROR Here

      strcpy(new->s,val);   // this is the part ehere I get Segmentation Fault
      new->next=NULL;
   }
  return new;
 }
```

you have allocated space for `new` that is of type `node` but you haven't allocated space for `new->s` which is a `pointer to char` so when you are copying the string it is hiving the segmentation fault.

your code should be like this:

```
 node* create(string val)
 {
   node* new = malloc(sizeof(node));

   if(new!=NULL)
   {
      new->s=malloc(strlen(val+1)*sizeof(char)); //add this line here
      strcpy(new->s,val);  
      new->next=NULL;
   }
  return new;
 }
```

Comment: It's still giving me segmentation fault

Comment: check your code carefully for correct allocation and check if length of `val` variable is giving correct in create function.